# jQuery .click method not working

Tags: jquery, html, click

I'm trying to change the value based on if the user clicks a button and I have this code, but nothing is happening when I click. It's after the document loads, so I know that isn't the problem.

```
$('#delete').click(function() 
{   
    document.getElementById("deletedHidden").value= "yes";  
    alert("Click hit.");    
});
```

and this is the html

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="delete" name="delete" type="button" value="Delete">
```

Comment: Is the alert firing? If it isn't, try commenting out `document.get...` and see if the alert works then. The problem is, in the HTML you displayed, there is no element with an ID of `deletedHidden`.

Comment: are you binding event after button is created? put your code to $(function () { ... })

Comment: Is that the whole HTML?  I can assume that's in a table, right?  What's `deletedHidden`?

Comment: that's a different element used somewhere else.

Comment: yes this is the only function not working.

Comment: @user2415335 Please post your full html and jquery in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential causes for your problem:

1) the element `#delete` does not exist at the time you bind the handler. Move the handler into a `$(document).ready` block, or use event delegation via `on()`.

2) the element `#deletedHidden` does not exist when the click handler fires. `getElementById` will return `null` if it can't find the element, and `null.value` will throw an exception. JavaScript will cease interpretation when it encounters an exception, which means the `alert` will never fire.

Comment: The element #deletedHidden has nothing to do with when this button is clicked. and it is in the $(document).ready.

Comment: I moved the alert before the .value change and still no fire. It's sitting inside the document.ready still though.